# Is it possible to connect a funny pipe to a polyethylene tube?

Tags: sprinkler-system

Title says it all.  Is it possible to connect a [funny pipe](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/outdoors/garden-center/toro/funny-pipe-100-ft-roll-60920.html) to a [polyethylene tube](http://www.dripdepot.com/kit-pop?mv_arg=1045)?  If so, what exactly do I need?  Here in Southern California, I tried going to Home Depot and Lowes, but none of the employees there were able to help me.

I'd like to set up a drip irrigation system, but if possible I'd like to use an existing but unused sprinkler system pipe as the water source.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you don't get a good answer here, I'd suggest trying a specialty plumbing type shop instead of the box stores. They'll have more depth of expertise and may help you come up with a creative solution.

Comment: I'd agree, but I note the "funny tube" is sold by Home Depot and is designed to work with "Toro Funny Pipe Fittings" so Home Depot should know. Perhaps Toro might know, if they have a customer contact?

Comment: The polyethylene tube has really, _really_ thin walls: ".600 OD x.700 ID."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to just use hose fittings, e.g. [Toro part 53389](https://www.shoptoro.com/Comergent/en/US/direct/Toro?cmd=ToroCatDisplayStyle&catKey=700705) to [this](http://www.agriculturesolutions.com/Hose-and-Faucet-Fittings/Toro-Loc-Eze-3/4-Female-Hose-Adapter-to-1/2-Irrigation-Tubing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The fittings used would depend on your connections:
As a tee: ins x ins x fth tee with a mth x funny pipe adapter
Elbow: ins x fth elbow with a mth x funny pipe adapter
Straight/ coupling: ins x fth adapter with mth funny pipe adapter.

Typically big box stores don't have what you need. Find your local sprinkler supply store if you have one.

Just keep in mind for every foot of funny pipe moving 5gpm you have a friction loss of 0.15 psi

Comment: Welcome Jason L! This question has been around for a number of years without a detailed answer, so this is especially appreciated! Would you mind spelling out the abbreviations of ins, fth and mth? Unfortunately I don't understand fittings, so I don't know what those mean! Thanks, and I hope we see more of you!